# Python / Tkinter : window losing fullscreen when another window get focus

Tags: python, tkinter, fullscreen, messagebox

I have a fullscreen app running with Python / Tkinter.
The main window is in fullscreen mode.

However, when I call a Toplevel window or a Messagebox, the main window lose fuulscreen and Operating System taskbars show.

Note: if I click again on the window, it get focus and fullscreen again.

Is there a way to prevent main window losing fullscreen when losing focus?

Here's a code and screenshot in which you can see the problem.

Thank you for you answers.

```
# coding: utf-8
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import askokcancel, showinfo, WARNING

#Création de la fenêtre
fenetre = Tk()
larg=fenetre.winfo_screenwidth()
haut=fenetre.winfo_screenheight()
fenetre.title("Tests")
fenetre.geometry(f"{larg}x{haut}+0+0")
fenetre.attributes("-fullscreen",1)

def fermeture():
    reponse = askokcancel(title='Confirmation', message='Quitter ?', icon=WARNING)
    if reponse == True:
        fenetre.destroy()

bouton_quitter=Button(fenetre,text="quitter", command=fermeture)
bouton_quitter.place(x=larg/2,y=haut/2)
fenetre.mainloop()
```

[image]

I tried to add `fenetre.after(500,ffocus)` to force the main window to get back focus after messagebox appears.

But this is not satisfying as:

- it will anyway lose focus for a short time, showing O.S. taskbars
- the 500 ms delay may be too short depending processor performance

I also tried to add `parent=fenetre` but that does not change behaviour.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252053/discussion-on-question-by-jouski-python-tkinter-window-losing-fullscreen-whe); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.